# Cosine of a Wiener process

Tags: probability-distributions, brownian-motion, riemann-sum

Let $W_t$ be a standard Brownian motion, i.e., $W_t \sim N(0,t)$. Define the random variable

$$X=\int_0^1\cos(W_t)dt$$

A similiar process, $Y_t=\cos(\omega t+\sigma W_t+\theta)$, with the uniform random variable $\theta\sim U(-\pi,\pi)$ and $\omega\in\Bbb R$, was analyzed by Cai and Wu [1], where the probability density was defined as

$$p_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$

Seeing that the process $Y_t$ has a density, how can I obtain the density of the simplified process $\cos(W_t)$ ? I expanded the integral as a Riemann sum,

$$X\approx\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{\cos\left( W_\frac{i}{n}\right)}=\frac{1}{n}\left(n\cos\left(W_\frac{1}{n}\right)+
(n-1)\left(\cos\left(W_\frac{2}{n}\right)-\cos\left(W_\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)+
(n-2)\left(\cos\left(W_\frac{3}{n}\right)-\cos\left(W_\frac{2}{n}\right)\right)+ \cdots +
2\left(\cos\left(W_\frac{n-1}{n}\right)-\cos\left(W_\frac{n-2}{n}\right)\right)+
\cos\left(W_1\right)-\cos\left(W_\frac{n-1}{n}\right)
\right)$$

and after rearranging the terms I got the sum
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{\cos\left( W_\frac{i}{n}\right)}=
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{-2(n-i+1)
\sin\left(\frac{W_\frac{i}{n}+W_\frac{i-1}{n}}{2}\right)
\sin\left(\frac{W_\frac{i}{n}-W_\frac{i-1}{n}}{2}\right)}$$

How can I progress from here?

---

[1] CAI, G. Q.; WU, C. Modeling of bounded stochastic processes. Probabilistic Engineering Mechanics, v. 19, n. 3, p. 197–203, 2004.

Comment: I find your question somewhat misleading. The process considered in the article is of the form $Y_t = \cos(\sigma W_t+\theta)$ for a uniformly distributed random variable $\theta$... your process $X_t$ is not exactly "similar" to $Y_t$ . In particular, it is not to be expected that $p$ is the density of $X_t$. Please feel free to correct me if I missed something about the article.

Comment: sure, but the random variable $\theta$ is constant in time. The cosine can them be partitioned in $\cos(\sigma W_t)\cos(\theta)-\sin(\sigma W_t)\sin(\theta)$. In order to understand the final form, I thought that I needed to break the integral into fundamental blocks, which is why I'm specifically asking about this one. 
But you are right. The process don't need to have the same distributions. I will edit it.

Comment: I'm just saying that $p$ is certainly not going to be the density of $X$. Using that $W_t \sim N(0,t)$ you can verify that $\mathbb{E}(X)>0$. If $Y$ is a random variable with density $p(y)=\frac{1}{\pi \sqrt{1-y^2}} 1_{(-1,1)}(y)$ then it has expectation zero... this shows that something doesn't fit here (or I'm misunderstanding your question). I think it's highly non-trivial to determine the distribution of $X$.

Comment: Yes, it is a definite integral in time of the cosine of a Wiener process, resulting on a random variable. I am not sure if it is well-defined, this being one question I am trying to resolve too.
About the density question, I have changed the question to explaing it better.

Comment: Actually, the $\theta$-case is noticeably simpler since $Y_t\stackrel d=\cos\theta$ for every $t$, whose distribution is well-known. // But what are you after: the PDF of $\cos(W_t)$ for some fixed $t$, or the PDF of $X$?

Comment: PDF of $X$ is what I am after. But, since you constated that the $\theta$-case is simpler, how would you do to find it?

Comment: If $\theta$ is uniform on $(0,2\pi)$, then, for every real number $z$, $\theta+z$ mod $2\pi$ is also uniform on $(0,2\pi)$, thus, for every $Z$ independent of $\theta$, $\cos(\theta+Z)\stackrel d=\cos\theta$. Now, surely you can compute the PDF of $\cos\theta$...

Comment: Related: [this](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/29504/20795) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/244807/91764).

Answer (score 2):

I edited my response many times to correct some mistakes. Sorry.

We can compute the density of $U_t=\cos(W_t)$ by appropriately separating the integral and a change of variable. For any measurable $f$

\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}(f(U_t)) &= \mathbb{E}(f(\cos(W_t))) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(\cos(w)) \mathbb{P}_{W_t}(w) \mathrm{d} w = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} f(\cos(w)) \mathbb{P}_{W_t}(w) \mathrm{d} w \\
& = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_{-1}^{1} f(u) \left( \mathbb{P}_{W_t}(\arccos(u)+2k\pi)+\mathbb{P}_{W_t}(\arccos(-u)+(2k+1)\pi) \right)\frac{ \mathrm{d} u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \\
&= \int_{-1}^1 f(u) \frac{\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{P}_{W_t}(\arccos(u)+2k\pi)+\mathbb{P}_{W_t}(\arccos(-u)+(2k+1)\pi)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \mathrm{d}u
\end{align}

From the first to the second line we need to separate odd and even integers but we can group the sums together after that.

So the density of $U_t=\cos(W_t)$ is
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}_{U_t}(u) = \frac{\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{P}_{W_t}(\arccos(u)+2k\pi)+\mathbb{P}_{W_t}(\arccos(-u)+(2k+1)\pi)}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}
\end{equation}

Numerical simulations for $\mathbb{P}_{U_t}$:

[image: Histogram and density of U_t]

The numerator is an infinite sum as it appears in the wrapped Gaussian. But there is this $\arccos$ and the denominator. I don't know if it can help to evaluate the density of the integral.

The problem is that $U_t$ is neither Gaussian nor independent at different time step which makes difficult to evaluate the density of the Riemann sum.

Numerical simulations give the following histogram for X:

[image: Histogram of X]

I don't have any idea of what function it could be.

Interestingly, using a sinus ie $U_t = \sin(W_t)$ seems tractable. It's probably because $U_t$ is centered. To get the density, just replace $\arccos$ by $\arcsin$ above. See the figures. For $\mathbb{P}_{U_t}$

[image: Histogram and density of U_t]

And for the density of $X$, I'm able to fit a density $ \propto \exp\left( -\frac{s}{1-x^2} \right) $:

[image: Histogram of X]

I hope it could be helpful.

Comment: I edited my answer many times because of calculus errors and wrong simulations. Now it should be correct.